# Phonegap with jquery and jquerymobile for BB

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, blackberry-webworks

I am developing for BlackBerry webworks, PhoneGap 1.9., Jquery and jquery mobile.
The example provided by PhoneGap works fine on the simulator until it includes jQuery library, where the application stops responding.

Add code to understand the situation. Someone could use the same technologies?

1)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Prueba</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.0.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Hello!</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

=> Result: crash

2) Using the jQuery version 1.6.4 for this post (http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10608)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Prueba</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.0.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Hello!</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

=> Result: crash

3) Without jquery mobile

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Prueba</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.0.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Hello!</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

=> Result: crash

4) Without jquery mobile

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Prueba</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.0.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Hello!</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

=> Result: works!

But I need jquery mobile. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What BlackBerry Smartphone and OS are you testing on?

Comment: Simulator 7.0.0.318 for WebWorks

Comment: Can you try it out on an actual device? I have noticed some inconstancies with the simulators.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not the jquery mobile file (unless it's a corrupted download) since I have been using the same version of jquery in multiple Blackberry projects.

Consider checking the compatibility of cordova-1.9 and json2.js with PhoneGap 1.9 and with Blackberry.

Of course, it's much simpler to just use the WebWorks SDK when developing for Blackberry since you get access to easier methods for dealing with Blackberry pecularities (and you can always strip out the Blackberry parts later when porting to other platforms). Check it out: https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/ (there are plenty useful samples)